# "The spell can cause much damage to enemies with special effects on them": is it ambiguous?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

It is a description about a skill of an hero in a game and it goes like this:

> The spell can cause much damage to enemies with special effects on them.

After I wrote it down, I wondered: would a native English speaker understand its intended meaning? I'm concerned that there may be two ways to understand this sentence:

1. This spell would cause damage to enemies who already carry special effects on themselves.
2. This spell would use its special effects to cause damage to enemies.

I want to express the meaning of the first sentence. Is the original wording ambiguous? Is there a simple way to make it unambiguous?

Comment: Here is a [similar question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123668/what-would-you-call-this-kind-of-prepositional-phrase).

Comment: I immediately understood option 1 and never saw option 2 until you pointed it out, and I think most people would not interpret it that way (2) because that’s not how a native speaker would word it if that’s what they meant.

Comment: Option 1 is clear to me.  Use it.

Comment: Also change "would" to "will."

Comment: Just replace "with" in your original sentence with "who have". By the way, if you *wanted* to mean option 2, place a comma after "enemies".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generally correct that one must be careful when using prepositional phrases (*with special effects*, *on them*) to make the antecedent clear. When it's not clear, the reader might infer either of two interpretations.

In this example, because *on them* modifies *effects*, we just need to figure out whether *with special effects* modifies *spell* or *enemies*. However, since we know that the antecedent is plural ("on *them*"), then the only valid antecedent is *enemies.*

Thus, the correct interpretation must be #1.

Comment: -1 The issue isn't the antecedent of "on them," it's the attachment of "with..." (to either the noun phrase "enemies" or the verb phrase "cause much damage...").

Comment: You are correct that the antecedent of "on them" is not really at issue. However, knowing what "them" refers to is the key to unlocking this mystery and removing the perceived ambiguity.